# how to move one table row to another table in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I want to move rows to another table by clicking on button.
clicking on up button moves 2nd table row to 1st and clicking on down moves 1st table to 2nd.

In HTML:

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tag Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="tag in vm.tags | filter: searchBar"
                    ng-init="selectedIndex = $index">
                    <td><span ng-click="vm.editTags(selectedIndex);"
                        tooltip="Click to edit tag">{{tag.name}}</span></td>
                    <td><span ng-click="vm.editTags(selectedIndex);"
                        tooltip="Click to edit tag">{{tag.status}}</span></td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove change-color"
                        ng-click="vm.removeTag(selectedIndex)" tooltip="Delete tag">
                    </span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="top-bottom-padding col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn change-color bg-white">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down glyphicon-lg"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="top-bottom-padding col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn change-color bg-white">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up glyphicon-lg"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

        <div class="clear pull-right col-sm-1">
          <br/>
            <button ng-disabled="vm.selectedOrder.status == 'Activated'"
                class="pull-left btn btn-primary margin-Left"
                ng-click="vm.editStatus();">Activated</button>
            <button ng-disabled="vm.selectedOrder.status == 'Paused'"
                class="pull-left btn btn-primary margin-Left"
                ng-click="vm.editStatus();">Paused</button>
        </div>
    <div class="clear top-bottom-padding col-sm-1">
        <table class="table table-color table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rotation Order</th>
                    <th>Tag Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- ng-sortable - External component used for re-arranging rows of table -->
            <tbody ng-sortable="{animation:150}">
                <tr ng-repeat="orders in  vm.rotationTable"
                    ng-class="{selected : orders == vm.selectedOrder}"
                    ng-click="vm.setSelected(orders)">
                    <td>{{orders.rotationOrder}}</td>
                    <td>{{orders.tagName}}</td>
                    <td>{{orders.status}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

in JS:-

```
// Code goes here



var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  myApp.controller('tagController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {

  var vm = this;  
  vm.tags = [
        {
            "name": "Tag A",
            "status": "Activated"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tag B",
            "status": "Paused"
        },
         {
             "name": "Tag C",
             "status": "Paused"
         },
         {
             "name": "Tag D",
             "status": "Activated"
         }
  ];
  vm.rotationTable = [
      {
          "rotationOrder": "1",
          "tagName": "Tag D",
          "status":"Activated"
      },
      {
          "rotationOrder": "2",
          "tagName": "Tag E",
          "status": "Paused"
      },
      {
          "rotationOrder": "3",
          "tagName": "Tag F",
          "status": "Activated"
      }
  ]
  vm.selectedOrder = null;
  vm.setSelected = function (order) {
      vm.selectedOrder = order;
      console.log(vm.selectedOrder);
  };

  vm.editStatus = function () {
      if (vm.selectedOrder.status == "Paused")
      {
          vm.selectedOrder.status = "Activated";
      }
      else if (vm.selectedOrder.status = "Activated")
      {
          vm.selectedOrder.status = "Paused";
      }
  };

     vm.addTags = function () {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: './views/admin/addNewTag.html',
          controller: 'addNewTagController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          resolve: {
              tagsData: function () {
                  return vm.tags;
              }
          }
      });
  };


  vm.editTags = function (whichTag) {
      vm.whichTag = whichTag;
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: './views/admin/updateTag.html',
          controller: 'updateTagController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          resolve: {
              tagsData: function () {
                  return vm.tags;
              },
              whichTag: function () {
                  return vm.whichTag;
              }
          }
      });
  };      

  vm.removeTag = function (index) {
      vm.tags.splice(index, 1);
  };

 }]);
```

you can see mu code here:http://plnkr.co/edit/bsoTjFpJrEu3nG6cnjci?p=preview

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `move`? The data has different structures in each array. Would be trivial if they were the same structure

Comment: move means selecting one row from first table and clicking on arrow to send to another table at the end same as vice versa.yeah if possible we can add id to tag table to maintain same data structure.

Answer (score 0):

To move an item from vm.tags to vm.rotationTable at the top

```
var selectedIndex = 0;// or any valid index from vm.tags
vm.rotationTable.splice(0, 0, vm.tags.splice(selectedIndex, 1)[0]);
```

To move an item from vm.rotationTable to vm.tags at the bottom

```
var selectedIndex = 0;// or any valid index from vm.rotationTable
vm.tags.splice(vm.tags.length - 1, 0, vm.rotationTable.splice(selectedIndex, 1)[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working the way I want.I want one row to be selected then click on arrow it will move to next table in end.

Comment: @Pallavi it's up to you to integrate into whatever event you need. This isn't a code writing service. The answer is showing you how to do it

Comment: do you think i havent tried its just error is in my logic.I know its not code writing service.and I am not asking to write code.i am just asking to help me to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
in html:-
<button type="button" class="btn change-color bg-white" ng-click="vm.moveRight();">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right  glyphicon-lg"></span>
 </button>

<button type="button" class="btn change-color bg-white" ng-click="vm.moveLeft();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left  glyphicon-lg"></span>
</button>
```

in js:-

```
vm.moveRight = function () {
             var selectedIndex = vm.selectedTag;
              vm.rotationTable.push(vm.selectedTag);
              vm.tags.splice(index,1);
             };

      vm.moveLeft = function () {
          var selectedIndex = vm.selectedOrder;// or any valid index from vm.tags
          vm.tags.push(vm.selectedOrder);//({ name: vm.tagsData.name, status: vm.tagsData.status });
          vm.rotationTable.splice(index, 1);
      };
```